# Verificar no formulário se password inserida é fácil

Tags: php, segurança, script, password

Pretendo criar um script para que no formulário de registo que tenho, verifique as password mais utilizadas e menos seguras.

Isto é, verificar por exemplo as passwords escritas pelos utilizadores e não permitir avançar no registo, como por exemplo as seguintes passwords:

- abc123
- abcdef
- 123456
- qwerty123
- 98765

A ideia é, haver mais segurança nas contas dos utilizadores que criam contas no meu site

Comment: Sugiro a utilização do plugin jQuery Complexify: http://www.devmedia.com.br/verificando-a-forca-da-senha-com-o-plugin-jquery-complexify/27088

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro é preciso determinar o que é uma senha forte e fraca, isso já é o inicio mais óbvio. Existem vários tipos de implementações, aqui você pode ver um exemplo comparando três senhas diferentes em vários serviços diferentes:

[image: Comparacao de senha]

Recomendo que [leia toda a explicação aqui](https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2012/04/zxcvbn-realistic-password-strength-estimation/), justamente onde tem essa imagem.

O Dropbox disponibilizou em código aberto o seu sistema de "analise de senhas", [pode ver aqui](https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn). Ele possui implementações em várias linguagens diferentes.

Se quiser uma lista com mais opções:

- [ZXCVBN](https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn)
- [Complexify](https://github.com/danpalmer/jquery.complexify.js/)
- [Passwdqc](https://github.com/odin-public/passwdqc-js)

Se quiser uma comparação, [veja aqui](http://password-policy-testing.wikidot.com/results).

---

Medir forças de senha é relativo, por mim extremamente falho. A força da senha será medida por um padrão, um critério que você acredita que é seguro. Inclusive por isso existe tanta diferença o resultado de uma biblioteca e uma outra biblioteca. O problema é que o atacante pode não seguir o seu padrão. É impossível determinar a força de uma senha se desconhece a técnica do atacante.

Inclusive, a senha "correcthorsebatterystaple" pode não ser considerada boa, segundo, por exemplo, o [Bruce Schneier](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2014/03/choosing_secure_1.html), esta e a mesma senha que o ZXCVBN, do Dropbox, considera mais segura.

---

Pessoalmente acredito que o mais importante é permitir o usuário usar 2FA, preferencialmente FIDO U2F e por enquanto também aceite o TOTP. Isso será o fator principal, se a pessoa descobrir a senha será barrado pela segunda autenticação.

Lembre-se de guardar a senha corretamente (usando Argon2, BCrypt, Scrypt ou PBDKF2, com altas dificuldades), isso atrasar de ataques "off-line" caso seu banco de dados tenha sido comprometido.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez isso possa ajudar.

No seu HTML:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
   <div class="search-box">
    <div class="caption">
     <h3>Advance Password Validation</h3>
     <p>Find to All</p>
    </div>
    <form action="" class="loginForm">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name">
      <input type="password" id="paw" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
      <input type="submit" id="submit" class="form-control" value="Submit">
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="aro-pswd_info">
    <div id="pswd_info">
     <h4>Password must be requirements</h4>
     <ul>
      <li id="letter" class="invalid">At least <strong>one letter</strong></li>
      <li id="capital" class="invalid">At least <strong>one capital letter</strong></li>
      <li id="number" class="invalid">At least <strong>one number</strong></li>
      <li id="length" class="invalid">Be at least <strong>8 characters</strong></li>
      <li id="space" class="invalid">be<strong> use [~,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,-,=,.,;,']</strong></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Pode estilizar com algum css:

```css
.alignleft {
float: left;
margin-right: 15px;
}
.alignright {
float: right;
margin-left: 15px;
}
.aligncenter {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto 15px;
}
a:focus { outline: 0 solid }
img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
.fix { overflow: hidden }
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
margin: 0 0 15px;
font-weight: 700;
}
html,
body { height: 100% }

a {
-moz-transition: 0.3s;
-o-transition: 0.3s;
-webkit-transition: 0.3s;
transition: 0.3s;
color: #333;
}
a:hover { text-decoration: none }



.search-box{margin:80px auto;position:absolute;}
.caption{margin-bottom:50px;}
.loginForm input[type=text], .loginForm input[type=password]{
margin-bottom:10px;
}
.loginForm input[type=submit]{
background:#fb044a;
color:#fff;
font-weight:700;

}


#pswd_info {
background: #dfdfdf none repeat scroll 0 0;
color: #fff;
left: 20px;
position: absolute;
top: 115px;
}
#pswd_info h4{
background: black none repeat scroll 0 0;
display: block;
font-size: 14px;
letter-spacing: 0;
padding: 17px 0;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
#pswd_info ul {
list-style: outside none none;
}
#pswd_info ul li {
   padding: 10px 45px;
}



.valid {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("https://s19.postimg.org/vq43s2wib/valid.png") no-repeat scroll 2px 6px;
color: green;
line-height: 21px;
padding-left: 22px;
}

.invalid {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("https://s19.postimg.org/olmaj1p8z/invalid.png") no-repeat scroll 2px 6px;
color: red;
line-height: 21px;
padding-left: 22px;
}


#pswd_info::before {
background: #dfdfdf none repeat scroll 0 0;
content: "";
height: 25px;
left: -13px;
margin-top: -12.5px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: rotate(45deg);
width: 25px;
}
#pswd_info {
display:none;
}
```

Já seu javascript(onde vai acontecer a magica) será assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('input[type=password]').keyup(function() {
  var pswd = $(this).val();
  
  //validate the length
  if ( pswd.length < 8 ) {
   $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
  } else {
   $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
  }
  
  //validate letter
  if ( pswd.match(/[A-z]/) ) {
   $('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
  } else {
   $('#letter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
  }

  //validate capital letter
  if ( pswd.match(/[A-Z]/) ) {
   $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
  } else {
   $('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
  }

  //validate number
  if ( pswd.match(/\d/) ) {
   $('#number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
  } else {
   $('#number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
  }
  
  //validate space
  if ( pswd.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\/]/) ) {
   $('#space').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
  } else {
   $('#space').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
  }
  
 }).focus(function() {
  $('#pswd_info').show();
 }).blur(function() {
  $('#pswd_info').hide();
 });
 
});
```

Espero que isso ajude clarear as ideias.

Referencia: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/advance-password-validation